# asp.net Export to Excel leaves [?] on line endings before carriage returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, export-to-excel

I have an some code to export data form an SQL database to an Excel spread sheet.

the data is entered via a web site and some of it contains multiple lines of information.

I need to preserve the multiple lines but excel 2007 continues to put an [?] at the end of each line.

Here's what I got so far

```
CellValue.ToString()  // this returns [?][?] at the end of each line for excel 2007 
                      // and a single [?] in excel 2010

CellValue.Replace("[//r]","")  // this works correctly for 2010 but still leaves a [?] for 2007

Cellvalue.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")  // this removes all the line breaks.
```

what can I replace the Environment.NewLine with in order to still have line breaks in both excel 2007 and 2010 (with no [?]) ?

Comment: Have you tried ASCII 13 + ASCII 10 ?

Comment: @Remou Thanks for you suggestion, but I'm not sure how to do that, could you provide an example?

Comment: Apparently, some input may be `lf` only, and some `crlf` ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019928/carriage-return-ascii-chr-13-is-missing-from-textbox-postback-values-when-used ). Excel would expect cr (ascii 13) and lf (ascii 10). Perhaps you can replace /r & /n separately to end up with just one and then replace that with Environment.NewLine? I am afraid I am only speaking from the point of view of Excel, hence the note rather than answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found on [egghead cafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/74/10124953/how-to-remove-the-carriage-return-from-string-while-pasting-content-to-excel-file.aspx)

```
CellValue.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n")
```

Excel only requires the line feed not the carriage return. Also I think I've been suffering some confusion between "[//r]" and "\r"

Answer (score 0):

cell.Text = "your firstlineyour secondline";

if you are getting the text from DB then:

cell.Text = textfromDB.Replace("\n", "");